# Aggregating estimates for weekly data

Tags: r, probability, prediction

I have a data set (in R) measuring the performance of all machines in a factory at the end of one week. Each machine has various metrics captured (feature vector) and the ppm defects (predicted variable) it generates. My problem statement needs me to estimate aggregate ppm defects for all machines in the factory.

I am thinking of fitting a mixture model to estimate parameters for a week, as my distribution of predicted variable is bimodal:

[image]
$$ $$
However, my problem needs me to then use the 12 weeks of estimated parameters to predict the defects that will be incurred in the 13th week. Something like a weighted moving average:

$$ ppm_{13} =  \sum_{i=1}^{12} w_i * ppm_i $$

Maybe if I can assume the dependence of 13th week estimate on the previous weeks using conditional probabilities, I would be able to weight each 12 prior week's observation to predict the 13th week. Any advice will be helpful.